# Powershell 4.0 script runs against local system but not other computers on network

Tags: powershell

I have built a script to pull details of a registry entry from every computer on our domain. It runs fine on my computer. It runs for a list of computers provided, but returns a blank value for them. It should be a 1 or a 0 (all systems have PS 4.0 installed and Remote Registry turned on).

```
$array =@() 
$keyname = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\Main' 
$computernames = Get-Content 
C:\PowershellandTextFiles\WindowsUpdate\CompIE.csv 
foreach ($server in $computernames) 
{ 
  $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',   
    $server) 
    $key = $reg.OpenSubkey($keyname) 
    $value = $key.GetValue('EnableAutoUpgrade') 
    $obj = New-Object PSObject 

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value 
    $server 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "IESet" -Value $value 

    $array += $obj  
  } 
    $array | select ComputerName, IESet
```

IESet is blank. What do I need to do to get this to return the value in the registry key from any computer polled ?

Comment: Have you looked at `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: I have tried Invoke-Command in a similar script. It does not work for systems other than the one I run it against either

Comment: Use the `-Authentication` parameter.  Likely with the `Kerberos` option.